# Can we override hashCode and equals method in Non hash Collection like ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java

I understood the purpose of overriding the equals() method and hashCode()  method. But my question can we override hashcode and equals in non-hash collection like ArrayList?

Comment: i think you can, but makes no sense to do so

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to do? You can't override methods within classes that already exist... but you could create your own collection classes and override hashCode and equals if you want. Usually collections classes are more interested in how their *elements* override hashCode and equals though. Please clarify the question.

Comment: You can override `equals()` and `getHashCode()` for any class that you create. When you override those they can be safely used as keys in a hash map. Overriding these methods is simply providing a means to tell two objects of that type apart.

Comment: @LeiYang: It can *absolutely* make sense to do so - it can be really useful to know whether one set is equivalent to another, for example. But it's not clear what the OP is actually asking at the moment... at least not to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet you must be correct. but the OP already said non-hash, and you metioned `set`, which is hash. am i mistaking?

Comment: @LeiYang: There's nothing to say that a set has to be implemented using hash codes. It's common to do so, but not a fundamental requirement.

Comment: @JonSkeet this completely exceeds my knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

The methods `equals()` and `hashCode()` are declared in `Object` (the parent of everything in Java), so technically yes, you can override them from any class.

As for the "sense" of doing it, that's up to you.

Why do you override them usually? Because you want two objects that are technically two different instances, but functionally the same instance, to be hashed the same way in a hash implementation (for example the `HashMap`).

Take this for example:

```
public class Id {
    private final String id;
    public Id(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

If you do the following:

```
Id id1 = new Id("1");
Id id2 = new Id("1");
id1.equals(id2); //<-- false
```

... you get `false` by comparing them because they are not the same instance.
Hence, if you were to use them into a key of an hash map, then the two objects would generate two different hashes and for that, would be treated as two separate keys.

However, for you the fact that the string `1` is the same in both may mean they are the same thing and should be considered as the same key.

So you override `equals()` and `hashCode()` accordingly.

If you need the same to be done on any kind of object (including `ArrayList`), then yes it makes sense
(Note: you usually need this when you need to use these objects as key of an hash - like an `HashMap`).

If you don't, then no it's not required.

As a side note, `ArrayList` is not a modifiable class so even if you wanted, you couldn't change the implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`.
What you may do though, is to wrap that list inside a class of your and then implement the methods as you wish.